# How to avoid code duplication in Java having one line difference in methods

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have following classes:

```
public class A {
   private List<B> list;

   ...

   public String findCreated() {
      return list.stream()
                 .
                 .some filter operations
                 .
                 .filter(b -> b.isCreated())
                 .
                 .some mapping
   }

   public String findRegistered() {
      return list.stream()
                 .
                 .some filter operations
                 .
                 .filter(b -> b.isRegistered())
                 .
                 .some mapping
   }
}

public class B {
    private boolean created;
    private boolean registered;

    ...

    public boolean isCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public boolean isRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    ...
}
```

I would like to refactor this code and have one *find* method in class A, because *find* methods differ by only one line. Do you know how to avoid duplicating code in this example?

Would any design pattern solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: in your example `filter` probably takes a `Predicated<B>`, so just let that be passed into your common method. Second, mostly unrelated hint: you can replace `b -> b.isRegistered()` with simple `B::isRegistered` (a method reference).

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class A {
   private List<B> list;

   private String find(Predicate<B> filter) {
      return list.stream()
                 .some filter operations
                 .filter(filter)
                 .some mapping;
   }

   public String findCreated() {
      return find(B::isCreated);
   }

   public String findRegistered() {
      return find(B::isRegistered);
   }
}
```